# MYSQL one day interval from 00:00:00 to 23:59:00

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time

I am trying to pickup 1 day previous records based on few dates and time stamps but my is not retrieving recorders from 00:00:00 to 23:59:00. I am using the follwoing criteria.

and ((cast(from_unixtime(`schedule`.`last_change_timestamp`) as date) = (curdate() - interval 1 day))
or (cast(`schedule`.`date_added` as date) = (curdate() - interval 1 day))
or (left(`jobsheet`.`actual_completion_date_set`, 10) = (curdate() - interval 1 day))
or (cast(from_unixtime(`orders`.`dateadded`) as date) = (curdate() - interval 1 day)))),

The records which I am missing are most likely related to `jobsheet`.`actual_completion_date_set` which is in this format 
'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' and I am using left 10 characters for interval. Please could someone provide some help as to how I can force all these dates to select all records from 00:00:00 to 23:59:00 the previous day.

Thanks,

Comment: what is your query so far?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
left(jobsheet.actual_completion_date_set, 10) = date_format(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

In MySQL, I find it safer to use `date_sub()` and `date_add()` for the built-in constants.  These are not returned as `datetime` or `date`, so strange things can happen with conversions to the dates.

Comment: I have changed my expression to this but this shows current date data which I don't want ((cast(from_unixtime(`schedule`.`last_change_timestamp`) as date) BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and curdate())

                or (cast(`schedule`.`date_added` as date) BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and curdate())

                or (cast(`jobsheet`.`actual_completion_date_set` as date) BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and curdate())

                or (cast(from_unixtime(`orders`.`dateadded`) as date) BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and curdate())) )